# Executing a stored procedure from an external file in migrations fails in Team City build

Tags: teamcity, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to team city builds and running into this issue.

1. Created a stored procedure and tried accessing it to run in Migrations.

   var sqlFile = "Scripts\StoredProc.sql";
               var baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
               var sqlFilePath = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, @"....", sqlFile);
               SqlFile(sqlFilePath);
2. This runs perfectly on the local environment but breaks on team city.
   The path that it takes is some random BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\

I know the way I am accessing the file with the path is wrong, anyone have any suggessions that can help me figure what virtual path I need to put here?

Comment: Migrations are usually executed when applications starts, not during the build. Could you show us your TeamCity build step that is failing? When those migrations are executed during TeamCity  process?

Comment: So decided to not have the stored procedure created from an external file, decided to write a powershell to run the scripts

Comment: Add the .sql scripts to the project as embedded resource and call them in your migration using SqlResource(). This way you don't have to worry about any directories and the files part of the deployment.